# How can I configure my IPython notebook so it always shows the execution time as part of the output?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Sometimes I execute a method that takes long to compute

```
In [1]:

long_running_invocation()

Out[1]:
```

Often I am interested in knowing how much time it took, so I have to write this:

```
In[2]:
    import time

    start = time.time()
    long_running_invocation()
    end = time.time()
    print end - start
Out[2]: 1024
```

Is there a way to configure my IPython notebook so that it automatically prints the execution time of every call I am making like in the following example?

```
In [1]:

long_running_invocation()

Out[1] (1.59s):
```

Comment: You may want to precise your thought.

Answer (score 9):

This ipython extension does what you want: https://github.com/cpcloud/ipython-autotime

load it by putting this at the top of your notebook:

`%install_ext https://raw.github.com/cpcloud/ipython-autotime/master/autotime.py
%load_ext autotime`

Once loaded, every subsequent cell execution will include the time it took to execute as part of its output.

Comment: that's great. I had to do instead $ sudo pip install ipython-autotime

Comment: You can use the execute_time plugin from the jupyter nbextensions project: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html. Once enabled from the jupyter_nbextensions_configurator, the time for each cell will be displayed within the cell (as a small box underneath your main code cell, but separate from the output)

Comment: autotime displays right after the cell output in Colab, is there a way to have a carriage return or line space?

Answer (score 2):

i haven't found a way to have every cell output the time it takes to execute the code, but instead of what you have, you can use cell magics: %time or %timeit

[ipython cell magics](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

You can now just use the `%%time` magic at the beginning of the cell like this:

```
%%time
data = sc.textFile(sample_location)
doc_count = data.count()
doc_objs = data.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

which when executed will print out an output like:

```
CPU times: user 372 ms, sys: 48 ms, total: 420 ms
Wall time: 37.7 s
```

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way to configure your ipython notebook in a way it automatically shows the execution time without running any `%%time` or `%%timelit` or `time.time()` in each cell, is by using ipython-autotime package.

Install the package in the begining of the notebook

```
pip install ipython-autotime
```

and then load the extension by running below

```
%load_ext autotime
```

Once you have loaded it, any cell run after this ,will give you the execution time of the cell.

And dont worry if you want to turn it off, just unload the extension by running below

```
%unload_ext autotime
```

It is pretty simple and easy to use it whenever you want.

And if you want to check out more, can refer to [ipython-autime documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-autotime/) or its [github source](https://github.com/cpcloud/ipython-autotime)